# what to use or how best to convert otto event bus (now that otto is deprecated)?

Tags: android, event-bus, otto

on Square's [github](https://github.com/square/otto) i found the following statement:

> > Deprecated!
>
> This project is deprecated in favor of RxJava and RxAndroid. These
>   projects permit the same event-driven programming model as Otto, but
>   they’re more capable and offer better control of threading.
>
> If you’re looking for guidance on migrating from Otto to Rx, this post
>   is a good start.

I have a legacy project using otto and im worried about the future of the project now. Does android have anything built in i can use as an event bus ?  Do you think [event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) would be a good one to swap otto with or are they in the same hole ? classic alternative is the observer pattern but otto is just way more clean.

Some alternatives:

[Event Bus with RxJava](https://lorentzos.com/rxjava-as-event-bus-the-right-way-10a36bdd49ba)

[Mediator pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator)

[Event Aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html)

[The state of event bus today](http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/061/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=309f4188e7-Android_Weekly_229&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-309f4188e7-337904097)

[RxBus](https://github.com/AndroidKnife/RxBus)

Comment: What do you mean same hole? It seems to still be supported, but just like Otto that could change tomorrow.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Rx? There's [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), but it's even more trouble to use it.

Comment: You can use whatever you want, or follow [a guide on RxJava event buses](https://lorentzos.com/rxjava-as-event-bus-the-right-way-10a36bdd49ba). This sort of question is generally prohibited since it's opinion-based. Try an approach, then come back here and ask a technical question if you run into issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Green Robot Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is good
and it will also be easy to migrate from otto.